# How to: Go to file (#) Go to for symbol in the same dialog

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am missing this feature from Sublime Text so much. Go to Symbol in Workspace feels so close to it and yet so far away.This is very useful in the following examples:

You have many classes that have the same symbol/function name, Pre-filtering the file lets you jump to the exact definition very fast

You know the name of the file, but you are not sure about the exact symbol/function name. Fuzzy searching it is super fast

You want to quickly preview the available symbols/functions in a given file

Here is a sample video demonstrating this feature in Sublime Text:

https://youtu.be/48f3N0hCaBU?t=109

If this is not currently possible, is it possible to implement as extension?

Comment: Ctrl+P Quick Open and its options gives you some of that Sublime functionality but not the sexiest bits.

Comment: @Mark thanks for your comment. What about adding these sexy bits via extension? If there are available APIs for "Go To File" and "Go To Symbol" in File it shouldn't be so hard. I guess the biggest challenge is changing the context of "Go To Symbol in File" to be based on the highlighted file instead of the one open in the editor.

Comment: I opened a feature request here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/78920

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created an extension that provide similar functionality:
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=Cmacu.gotoanything

Answer (score 1):

This is being added in v1.44.  See https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/vnext/release-notes/v1_44.md#navigate-from-files-into-symbols

> You can now continue to navigate into symbols of a file result simply
>   by typing `@`. For the file that is currently selected, all symbols will
>   appear and the editor will open in the background to reveal the active
>   symbol.

[image: quick pick file to symbol]